# Building OpenCV for Java on Windows x64 with Cmake

Tags: java, windows, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am building OpenCV 420 for Java on Windows using cmake including the comtributed (extra) modules. I am successful in doing the cmake processes to generate the VS 2017 project. The VS project, set for x86 target, compiles and generates opencv-420.jar and opencv_420.dll. The opencv_420.dll is 37158kb in size. It contains all of the dependent libraries (dlls) created by the compile process. This jar and dll pair work correctly with the two files giving full access from Java to all opencv functions including the contributed ones. This shows that the varions dependant dlls are being merged into the single library opencv_420.dll.

Next I created a folder for x64 target, copied the x86 folder I used for the above x86 project and set the platform to x64. I run cmake successfully, generate the VS project and it compiles successfully as far as I can tell (there is a lot going I don't fully understand). This generates an x64 opencv-420.jar and an opencv_420.dll as expected. However, the opencv_420.dll is small at 2621kb and when I try to run the application it fails with can't find dependent libraries. I have determined this dll does not contain the the dependent libraries like the x86 dll does.

I have been over the cmake files and the VS project and can't seem to locate the difference between the x86 and x64 projects that causes the dependent dlls to not be merged into the opencv_420.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this one myself. Talk about not seeing the forest for the trees! There was a difference between the x86 and x64 cmake options that I just did not see until some reading I was doing today triggered the aha moment. I needed the Java Fat Jar option enabled in the x64 config as it was in the x86 config. All good now.